# Implementing Callbacks / Deferred Objects with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback, deferred

Below is a function that is called when a user clicks the "Save" button on a form. When the PreSaveAction function returns true, the form will be submitted. If false is returned, nothing will happen. I'm using an AJAX call to here to validate form values and would like to have PreSaveAction return true if validateUniqueStaff succeeds, and vise versa if it fails.

```
function PreSaveAction() { 
    $.ajax({
        url: listUrl,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: validateUniqueStaff,
        error: function (data) {
            alert("Error: Problem with the AJAX request");
        }  
    }); 

    //if (validateUniqueStaff succeeds) return true, else return false
}
```

My trouble is that I can't figure out how to incorporate a deferred object here. I've tried running the ajax call synchronously instead, which works in Chrome, but not in IE8 (a requirement).

I'm absolutely stumped. Any advice would be hugely appreciated! Let me know if I can provide any other information.

Comment: And what does ` validateUniqueStaff` look like ?

Comment: You are not showing what attempt you have made at implementing deferred here. The other thing to question is why you even need to implement deferred.  Why not just have success callback initiate the actual save action? Or rather have that save action called from within `validateUniqeuStaff` if that is where your validation occurs.

Comment: @adeneo         validateUniqueStaff gets an input on the form and iterates through the returned JSON to look for a match

Comment: @MikeBrant     I haven't been able to figure out how to initiate the save action on a form directly, this is in MOSS 2010. That would make things much simpler. I felt this was an opportunity to learn about callbacks at the least. I'm not expecting the answer, but any guidance would be helpful!

Comment: @Bread So I guess the question is here: Why do you need to return true/false to indicate success?  You seem to want to try to apply a procedural paradigm here.  Oftentimes in js, you would see the AJAX success trigger the validateUniqueStaff function, which in turn might call whatever your save function is upon success.  Why do you care about returning true/false from `PreSaveAction()` in such a case?

Comment: @MikeBrant     Unfortunately I'm trying to fit this within the boundaries of SharePoint, which is why I care about `PreSaveAction()`, which is called by default when a user clicks submit on a form. I didn't find much documentation on the function that is called onclick... see here: 

`if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$m$g_400e2089_e5e7_4ffa_ad0c_763bb1cae3c4$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RightRptControls$ctl00$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem", "", true, "", "", false, true))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `PreSaveAction()` is asynchronous.  You can't return a success or failure value from that function.  It will return long BEFORE the ajax call has completed.

For asynchronous calls (such as Ajax calls), you HAVE to process the result in a callback that gets called sometime later.  You can't pretend to use synchronous coding techniques with an asynchronous operation.  It just won't work.  `PreSaveAction()` returns long before the ajax call is done so it's return value will not know the end result of the Ajax call.

If your SharePoint environment requires `PreSaveAction()` to return `true/false` and you need to do an Ajax operation in order to figure out if you should return `true` or `false`, then you're in a bind.  You could make the Ajax call be synchronous, but that's generally a horrible user experience because it locks up the browser during the Ajax call and if you're going cross domain, you can't do synchronous anyway.

---

The best solution would be to understand what your options are with the `PreSaveAction()` function and see if you can pass a callback into it that will be called with the final result when the asynchronous Ajax call is done.

That would work something like this:

```
function PreSaveAction(callback) { 
    $.ajax({
        url: listUrl,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            var retVal = validateUniqueStaff(data);
            // call the callback to report the results of validation
            callback(retVal);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("Error: Problem with the AJAX request");
            callback(false);
        }  
    }); 
}
```

---

The little bit of searching I did on `PreSaveAction()` in SharePoint indicates that it has to be synchronous.   It was designed for client-side validation only (without Ajax calls to the server).  To use it, you will have to return `true` or `false` directly from it and thus you can't use asynchronous Ajax calls in your `PreSaveAction()` implementation because the result won't be known in time.  You might be able to make your Ajax call synchronous (which I hate because it can be a bad user experience) or you need to find a different way to do your server-assisted validation.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually possible!

You need to use the developer tools (F12) to get the current java script code behind the button.

Here's how to proceed next:

```
    //1. unbind the current handler:

         var saveButton = ...;   //your id (looks like ctl00_***)
         var saveButtonCallBack = ...; //call back id (looks like ctl00$...)

    //2. When document is ready

        jQuery(saveButton).unbind('click').click(function(){

                    PreSaveActionPeter(

                        function (){        
                            WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(saveButtonCallBack, "", true, "", "", false, true))
                        }
                    ) 
                });

    //3. Define your function:

        function PreSaveActionPeter(callBack)
            {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: *your url*,
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: {
                        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.d.results.length > 0) {
                            callBack();
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                    }
                });     

                return true;
            }

//4. Override of the default PreSaveAction

function PreSaveAction()
    {       
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For form validation, it has been standard practise since time immemorial to issue `form.submit()`  from a submit handler on successful validation, and to return false unconditionally.

Presumably, in the SharePoint environment, you can do the same but with the added minor convolution, in this case, that validation be undertaken only after successful receipt of an AJAX response.

Exactly what you write depends on what your `validateUniqueStaff` returns.

Assuming `validateUniqueStaff` to return a boolean (valid/invalid), you would write:

```
function PreSaveAction() {
    var form = this;
    //disable Save button here
    $.ajax({
        url: listUrl,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json"
    }).then(validateUniqueStaff, function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        return new Error(textStatus);
    }).then(function(valid) {
        if(valid) {
            form.submit();
        } else {
            return $.Deferred.reject(new Error('Validation failure')).promise();
        }
    }).fail(function(e) {
        alert(e.message);//this will be either the AJAX error message or the validation failure message
    }).always(function() {
        //re-enable Save button here
    });
    return false;
}
```

Or (more elegantly from PreSaveAction's point of view), assuming `validateUniqueStaff` to return a Promise that is resolved on success or rejected on failure, you would write :

```
function PreSaveAction() {
    var form = this;
    //disable Save button here
    $.ajax({
        url: listUrl,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json"
    }).then(validateUniqueStaff, function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        return new Error(textStatus);
    }).then(form.submit, function(e) {
        alert(e.message);//this will be either the AJAX error message or the validation failure message
    }).always(function() {
        //re-enable Save button here
    });
    return false;
}
```

I really don't think you should be considering synchronous AJAX, which is as unreliable as it is unnecessary.

Comment: BTW, did you know that stackExchange has a site dedicated to [SharePoint](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com)?